# Unable to create documentation_part for api_gateway using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create documentation_part resource for my api_gateway using terraform but it is failing saying invalid json format. I tried giving the properties message as a string/JSON and all the possible variations but in vain.
Can someone let me know what am I doing wrong here?

1. Option 1: directly passed the value to the variable

   variable "cors_properties" {
   default = <<EOF
   "{"summary" : "CORS support"}"
   EOF
   }
2. Option 2: added the below in xyz.json file and passed the path to the field

   {
   "summary": "CORS support"
   }
3. Option 3: passed it as a string variable

The error that I am getting is as below:

Error: reading API Gateway Documentation Part: BadRequestException: Documentation part properties must be a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

In your option 1, you seem to have missed the escape sequence for double quotes, and I am guessing it may be same issue with your option 3. Have you tried adding escape sequence? They have example of that in their documentation:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_documentation_part" "example" {
  location {
    type   = "METHOD"
    method = "GET"
    path   = "/example"
  }

  properties  = "{\"description\":\"Example description\"}"
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "example" {
  name = "example_api"
}
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_documentation_part

For your option 2, you could use file function, something like below:

```
properties  = file("${path.module}/cors_properties.json")
```